# Discord.py bot will not join vc

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make my discord.py bot to join the vc that im in. But when i run the command, the bot does not want to join the vc. How can i fix this problem? Thanks. Code below.

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
  await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs of [`discord.Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) (where you did `ctx.message.author.voice`...), `voice_channel` is not a valid attribute. `channel` is a valid attribute instead.

Also, you don't have to do `ctx.message.author`, instead use `ctx.author`. Much faster.

So, your variable `channel` can be defined like this and you should connect to the channel like so:

```py
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
await channel.connect()
```

This should work.

Comment: I tried this and it still does not join the VC. I dont get any errors as well.

Comment: @ColeTMK Are you using an errorhandler to catch errors? I just looked at your code again and it seems that `bot.join_voice_channel` isn't an appropriate method either. Which discord.py version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.2. Discord.py 1.0.1